# Redundant variable while creating matrix by list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I am trying to fill up my `matrix` with zeros. Unfortunatelly, in the following example, variables `x` and `y` are redundand:

```
self.matrix = [[0 for x in range(0, self.N)] for y in range(0, self.N)]
```

Multiplying list, copy only references what of course is not what I am expecting:

```
>>> matrix = [[0] * 5] * 5
>>> matrix
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
>>> matrix[1][1] = "X"
>>> matrix
[[0, 'X', 0, 0, 0], [0, 'X', 0, 0, 0], [0, 'X', 0, 0, 0], [0, 'X', 0, 0, 0], [0, 'X', 0, 0, 0]]
```

So, is there any solution **using a list comprehension** to avoid redundand variables (`x` & `y`)?

Comment: @Ashwini: How is that helpful?

Comment: If I am not wrong then his problem is that when he's adding a value to a particular list item, it is also getting added to the other lists inside the list named matrix.
and http://stackoverflow.com/a/8713681/846892 explains this behaviour of lists.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: He knows about that behaviour. The question is an entirely different one, though...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The common idiom is to assign the result to the variable `_`, which signals a possible reader of your code that the value will not be used:

```
[[0]*self.N for _ in range(self.N)]
```

As you see, we can use the `[0]*size` idiom for the inner list because `0` is an immutable value. Also, you can call `range` with only one argument, in which case it is treated as the upper bound, with 0 being the lower bound).

If you want, you can build yourself a list build helper that supports creating lists of arbitrary nesting depth:

```
def make_multi_list(dim, func):
  if not dim: return func()
  return [make_multi_list(dim[1:], func) for _ in range(dim[0])]
```

Usage:

```
>>> make_multi_list((2, 2), lambda: 0)
[[0, 0], [0, 0]]
>>> make_multi_list((3, 2, 1), lambda: 0)
[[[0], [0]], [[0], [0]], [[0], [0]]]
```

Comment: Thanks, that is what I am looking for! And very nice example you got me.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could do:

```
from itertools import repeat

self.matrix = [list(repeat(0, self.N)) for _ in range(0, self.N)]
```

Comment: Thanks, you're right. I've fixed the code. Using the repeat function isn't necessary when the language already supports this feature.